# How do you use reverse-query in Marklogic to send actual message to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, marklogic

How do you grab an incoming message, run a reverse-query and if there is a match then alert Kafka with the full text of the original message ?

I currently have this working as an alert and my rule invokes xdmp:http  :

```
xdmp:http-post("http://localhost:8082/topics/MyTopicName",
<options xmlns="xdmp:http">
<data>{'{"records":[{"value": {"my alert" :   "Content updated." } }]}'
</data>
<headers>
<content-type>application/vnd.kafka.json.v1+json</content-type>
</headers>
</options>);
```

But instead of the string "Content updated" i want to send the original incoming message.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your code example is running as an "action". If so, it should have some external variables declared at the top as described in the documentation: [Actions to Execute When an Alert Fires](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/alerts#id_34775)

The `$alert:doc` variable should contain the document that matched your rule so you can use it as the data for your http post.

[edit] Adding detail about sending the XML document embedded in JSON:

Assuming you are using the confluent REST proxy described here https://www.confluent.io/blog/a-comprehensive-open-source-rest-proxy-for-kafka/,  I think you need to encode it into the JSON as a record value object. You could add some code like this to create your payload

```
let $payload := 
  xdmp:quote(
    object-node {
      "records" : array-node {
        object-node {
          "my alert" : xdmp:quote($alert:doc)
        }
      }
    }
  )
```

and then you can send that as the data in your post

```
xdmp:http-post("http://localhost:8082/topics/MyTopicName",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
    <data>{$payload}</data>
    <headers>
      <content-type>application/vnd.kafka.json.v1+json</content-type>
    </headers>
  </options>
);
```

Like I said in the comments though, I'm not a Kafka expert so I haven't checked that that actually works. It's one way of constructing a JSON payload that embeds an XML document as a property of the "value" object though.

The other approach you might think about is to just pull out the fields you want from your XML document using XPath and pass those as properties of the "value" object in the JSON. That way you are not passing the whole XML but rather, just the fields that you need.

Comment: Thanks James.  I get an XDMP-NOTSIMPLE error and i cant seem to find anything related to it.  My xdmp code is        

    xdmp:http-post("http://localhost:8082/topics/MyTopic",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
    <data>{$alert:doc}</data>
    <headers>
    <content-type>application/xml</content-type>
    </headers>
    </options>);

Comment: My xml file is a simple ... single node with text.

Comment: You need to convert your document into the string that you want sent as the body. This should work: `<data>{xdmp:quote($alert:doc)}</data>`

Comment: That definitely worked in getting rid of the XDMP-NOTSIMPLE error James !  However i dont see the message on my Topic.  The logs at every level do not give me any errors and the Kafka consumers draws a blank.  My guess is it got past the validation but is failing elsewhere and xdmp is not giving me enough information.  Ill keep trying ...

Comment: OK, yeah, I wasn't actually looking at the Kafka side of this as that's not my area expertise. Are you using the confluent REST proxy https://www.confluent.io/blog/a-comprehensive-open-source-rest-proxy-for-kafka/ ? If so, it looks like it requires a specific JSON format. I don't know what you are actually trying to accomplish but is you want to sent the actual XML document through as a "value". I'll update my answer with an example of that code as it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Hi James ... thats exactly what im trying to do ... send the actual XML doc through as a "value".

Comment: I've minimal knowledge of XQuery so couldn't debug the above code. Did you get a final code snippet that works in query console to send messages to a topic on kafka queue? @Dee